# Apple silicon M1 compatibility with TexStudio

Tags: texstudio, mac

Anybody else had issues with TexStudio on an M1 MacBook (2020 MacBook Air).

MacTex installs fine, alternate Intel editors eg TexMaker install fine & work, but TexStudio cannot open & prompts an error. Not even R click ‘allow this app’ as unidentifiable developer, and no tick box on R click to force open w Rosetta.

Although TexMaker also Intel app and (I assume) opens w Rosetta by default.

Any ideas?

Comment: what version of TeXStudio are you using? It's at version 3.0.3.

Comment: Thanks @HerbSchulz - on point, it was v 3.0.2, updated now to v3.0.4 and it works fine. Rookie mistake ;)

Comment: TexStudio is working for you in Apple Silicon M1 natively or with Rosetta? In my case I can't open it (I don't want to install Rosetta).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Closed: thanks to @HerbSchulz as above, a simple update from TexStudio v.3.0.2 to v3.0.4 solved the issue.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/203843)

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke he/she is the author, and I think this qualifies as an answer.

Comment: @brentocarrigan Please accept your answer to close this question.